# Entropy decoder in vlc

Tags: h.264, vlc, entropy, decoder, quantization

Where is the place with entropy decoding in VLC player source code [(GitHub link)](https://github.com/sunqueen/vlc-2.2.1.32-2013)?
I found a place with parsing NALs and frame-slices in VLC decoder, but I can't find any mention of entropy decoder or quantized coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code should be in ffmpeg, because VLC uses external libraries.

Comment: Yeah, found it out, when saw functions like ffmpeg_OpenCodec and more...
Anyway, thanks you!